# jQuery dialog: can I call this code snippet it's constructor?

Tags: jquery, constructor, dialog, modal-dialog

When initializing a jQuery dialog, can I refer to this code snippet as the 'constructor' for the dialog?

```
newDialog.dialog({
    modal: true,
    resizable: false,
    width: '600px',
    height: 'auto',
    autoOpen: false,
    title: 'This is a dialog',
    close: function() {
        newDialog.remove();
    }
});
```

(I know in Java or Apex, a constructor refers to creating an object. But I'm wondering if it's applicable in this instance, even though a dialog is not an object.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quick answer is no, your provided code example is not the constructor, but to go into more detail, what you are actually doing is passing in an a javascript object with key:values that the dialog class looks for in order to initialize a dialog object.

Internally, the $.dialog class calls a `_create` function, which is the dialog object's constructor (because, by definition, a constructors job is to create an object), but, the dialog class gives you the option to pass in an options object, which helps in the creation of the dialog object.

Your options object looks like this:

```
{
    modal: true,
    resizable: false,
    width: '600px',
    height: 'auto',
    autoOpen: false,
    title: 'This is a dialog',
    close: function() {
        newDialog.remove();
 }
```

So your code is essentially doing this:

1. Call the $.dialog() function made available via the JQuery UI API
2. Passing in an "options" object with your own custom values
3. Internally, the dialog() function calls the _create method (a private constructor used by the dialog class)
4. The _create method then takes the options object you passed into it and configures your dialog object according to your specifications.
5. Now your dialog object has been created, and has been assigned to your `newDialog` variable.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

No.

Constructors in JavaScript are generally used in tandem with the `New` keyword to create new objects.  While .dialog() may eventually call a constructor, your code does not.

It makes more sense to say you are "initializing" the plugin instead.

Answer (score 0):

Not really

jQuery widgets have a `_create()` method, which is actually the constructor of the widget (dialog): http://api.jqueryui.com/jQuery.widget/#method-_create

By calling the dialog() method, you will of course eventually invoke the constructor. But dialog() itself is not the constructor.